# customize "can" function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions, acl, helper

how i can customize @can function in laravel?

i want revoke specific permission from user by not delete permission from permissions table.
the users that have admin group can create users and give permission to them by multiple roles.
the super admins can revoke a permission from users but they can't delete permission from table, they 
can only revoke by adding permission to another table for example revoked_permissions.
now i want customize @can for ignore permissions that exists on revoked_permissions.

Comment: How are permissions divided?

Comment: permissions table and revoked_permissions table, revoked_permissions contains permissions that super admin revoke from users.

Comment: Is it divided by table?

Comment: yes it divided..

Comment: You can set role in laravel / App / Providers / AuthServiceProvider.php

Comment: what it function does?

Comment: Separate permissions separately
Easier than table

Comment: thank you to answer. but my question is "how i can customize 'can' function in laravel."

Comment: If you do so,
How about trying to increase authority?